# How to get the last active process

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm working on a program that will enter difficult to type text into the control that has focus in whatever application the user is currently using. (I'm using SendKeys.Send in VB.NET.) The problem is, I can only get a random list of processes or the current process, which is my application. How do I get the *previous* process that the user had open.

Comment: Thanks to nobody, I found a solution. I used EnumWindows went through processes starting with my own (compared the handle with Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle), then weeded out processes with no titles (GetWindowText) and those not visible (IsWindowVisible). The results are in zOrder and are correct.